# Service Userpoints : Missing required argument points

Tags: userpoints, services

My environment : Drupal 7 & service 3.x

I use userpoints and service-userpoints. I want to CRUD userpoints.

So i create a xmlrpc server and test it by Postman from Chrome store.

The xml code is belowed:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>pointss.add</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>uid</name>
            <value>
              <int>1</int>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>points</name>
            <value>
              <int>150</int>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>description</name>
            <value>
              <string>test for xmlrpc service</string>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

"pointss" is my userpoints-api's alias

i connect successful but got the message belowed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

faultCode
                    
                        401
                    
                
                
                    faultString
                    
                        Missing required argument points

How can i fix my xml body?
Does anybody have experience?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it.

The XMLRPC format is belowed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>pointss.addpoints</methodName>
   <params>
     <param>
           <name>uid</name>
           <value><int>1</int></value>
           <name>points</name>
           <value><int>150</int></value>
           <name>tid</name>
           <value><int>18</int></value>
           <name>operation</name>
           <value><string>test for operation</string></value>
           <name>description</name>
           <value><string>test for description</string></value>
           <name>entity_type</name>
           <value><string>node</string></value>
           <name>entity_id</name>
           <value><int>1</int></value>
     </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```

If somebody use service3.x and userpoints service, i hope i can help you.